# Which noble houses were destroyed during the Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Several major and minor houses were destroyed during the 8 seasons of *Game of Thrones*. The Boltons are gone. So are the Tyrells. Are all of the Mormonts dead? And the Umbers too?

Which major and minor families were destroyed?

By destroyed, I mean that all known members of the family are dead - not just that the family was unseated from their holdings. (You could say that the Targaryen family still exists while Jon Snow still stands.)

---

Mike Scott makes a good point that cadet branches, branches along a female line, and women married to other families might still be part of the family.

For families that follow only the male line, if a woman marries into another family, her children have claims to her husband's holdings, not to her father's holdings.

Cadet branches are the lines of a male ruler's younger sons, and they still have a claim to the family holdings. If a cadet branch exists, then it counts.

Illegitimate children have no claim to their parents' titles and lands in Westerosi tradition, so they and their children don't count for this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all of Westeros uses "Primogeniture" inheritance. That is: oldest legitimate son, then other sons, then daughters, then closest male relative. So a woman married into another family could still inherit. One of the reasons the Lannisters wanted Tyrion to marry Sansa.

Answer (score 41):

## Known Extinct Houses

These Houses were alive at the start of the first episode of the TV series or book series, but known/believed to be dead by the end of the final episode. Or are known to be dead by the end of the most recently published book.

1. **[House Tyrell](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Tyrell)** - Major House. Lady Olenna Tyrell was last survivor.
   Poisoned by Jaime Lannister after the siege of Highgarden.
2. **[House Bolton](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Bolton)** - Vassal House to Starks. Lord Ramsay Bolton was
   the last survivor. Killed by Sansa Stark after the Battle of the
   Bastards.
3. **[House Mormont](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Mormont)** - Vassal House to Starks. Lady Lyanna Mormont and
   her cousin, Jorah Mormont, were the last survivors. Both were killed
   during the Battle of Winterfell by wights.
4. **[House Karstark](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Karstark)** - Vassal House to Starks. Lady Alys Karstark was
   the last survivor. Killed in the Battle of Winterfell.
5. **[House Clegane](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Clegane)** - Vassal House to Lannisters. Ser Gregor Clegane
   and Sandor Clegane were the last survivors. Killed each other in a
   duel during the siege of King's Landing.
6. **[House Umber](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Umber)** - Vassal House to Starks. Ned Umber was the last
   survivor. Killed by the White Walkers during the slaughter of Last
   Hearth.
7. **[House Baelish](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Baelish)** - Vassal House to Arryns. Lord Petyr Baelish was
   the last survivor. Killed by Arya Stark during his trial for the
   killing of Lady Lysa Arryn.
8. **[House Hollard](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Hollard)** - Vassal House to Baratheons. Ser Dontos Hollard
   was killed by Petyr Baelish's soldiers; his payment for helping Lady Sansa escape the Purple Wedding.
9. **[House Elliver](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Elliver)** - Vassal House to Starks. Last survivors were
   slaughtered at the Red Wedding.
10. **[House Grayson](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Grayson)** - Vassal House to Starks. Last survivors were
     slaughtered at the Red Wedding.
11. **[House Brownbarrow](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Brownbarrow)** - Vassal House to Starks. Last survivors
     were slaughtered at the Red Wedding.
12. **[House Darry](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Darry)** - Vassal House to Tullys. Last survivor was an
     8-year-old boy named Lyman Darry. Killed by Gregor Clegane during the
     War of the Five Kings.

## Maybe Extinct Houses

These were thought to be extinct at one time during the TV series, but were either revived, or the fate is unknown.

- **[House Martell](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Martell)** - Major House of Dorne. House was thought to be
  extinct during the TV series when Euron Greyjoy captured the last
  surviving princesses of Dorne and gave them to Cersei Lannister as a
  gift. Cersei killed both of them. The final episode introduced a new
  prince of Dorne but did not mention if he was a member of House
  Martell.
- **[House Whent](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Whent)** - Vassal House to Tullys. Lady Catelyn Stark
  mentioned a Lady Whent in the first book, but her fate is unknown.
  House Whent's lands were given to Janos Slynt for his help in
  betraying Eddard Stark. Unknown if the Whent lands were given
  because House Whent recently went extinct (near the end of 1st book
  or near the start of 2nd book) or if House Whent was unseated
  during the War of the Five Kings.

That comes to 12 (maybe 14 houses) that went extinct during the TV series. Note that most of the extinct houses were vassals to the Starks.

## Extinct and then Revived Houses

- **[House Baratheon](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Baratheon_of_Dragonstone)** - Was extinct after the death of King Stannis
  Baratheon, but revived after Gendry was recognized as the son of
  King Robert Baratheon.

## Extinct Before Book & TV Series Began

These houses went extinct before the TV and book series.

- **[House Blackfyre](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Blackfyre)** - Vassal house of Targaryens. Maelys Blackfyre
  was the last survivor. This house went extinct decades before the TV
  series during a war between different branches of the Targaryens for
  control of the throne.
- **[House Reyne](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Reyne)** - Vassal house of Lannisters. Lord Reyne rebelled against the Lannisters and was destroyed by Lord Tywin Lannister. None of his family are thought to survive.

## Extinct Long Ago

These are sometimes mentioned only in passing in one or more stories.

- **House Durwell**
- **House Durandon**
- **House Mudd**
- **House Qoherys**
- **House Cole**
- **House Cargyll**
- **House Casterly**
- **House Justman**
- **House Lothston**
- **House Amber**
- **House Strong**
- **House Tarbeck**
- **House Towers**
- **House Frost**
- **House Greyiron**
- **House Greenwood**
- **House Gardener**
- **House Toyne**
- **House Harroway**
- **House Hoare**

Comment: Were these houses Elliver, Grayson, Brownbarrow ever mentioned in the show? I have never heard of them. And as Mike says, House Blackfyre went extinct in male line decades before Robert's Rebellion, during the reign of King Jaehaerys II.

Comment: If you are including houses that went extinct long before the TV show, you should probably include **House Reyne** too, given their destruction was contemporary to most of first seasons' main characters and it _is_ mentioned in the show when Cersei Lannister explains to Margaery Tyrell the meaning of the _Rains of Castamere_ song.

Comment: How about the house of Barristan Selmy?

Comment: @Termatinator Harvest Hall passed to Barristan's cousin (As did his betrothed) when he donned the white cloak. At least in the books

Comment: Technically Sansa didn't kill Ramsay. Ramsay's dogs did.

Comment: Shouldn't Martell be on this list?  Or did they legitimize a bastard to take the family name?  In the show they mentioned a "new prince of Dorne" but I don't think they ever said a name.

Comment: The penultimate paragraph mentions “two houses [that were] extinct well before the TV series,” but the ultimate paragraph only mentions Blackfyre. That same paragraph references “another answer” that does not appear to exist, at least in the form you describe. I assume the other was Targaryen; if not, it would also more-or-less follow (it’s unclear if the wider world is aware of Aegon Targaryen, but even if they are they aren’t likely to accept any of his children as legitimately continuing that House).

Comment: @KRyan: It looks like a previous version of the answer had House Baratheon listed there, but it was then moved up without changing the "two houses" text.

Comment: @bruglesco: She didn't poison herself as much as Jaime offered her a non-bloody death, which she took him up on.

Comment: Stannis died in episode 50. Wasn't House Baratheon still alive until episode 60 when Tommen suicided?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Depends whether you count a secret Lannister bastard as a Baratheon or not.

Answer (score 9):

As of now, the following Game of Thrones houses are extinct:

- House Tyrell
- House Bolton
- House Mormont
- House Karstark
- House Clegane
- House Umber

Comment: More than half of these were vassals of House Stark. Clearly the Starks take bad care of their protégés.